# attaching event handler to whole alphabets or just to one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

- I iterated fruits array through map method and displayed those elements in the browser.

  - but on each click of fruit, I need to display corresponding alert with fruit name a respectively
  - but now in my click I see only for a and when I click alphabet b it should b
  - do I need to attach event handler for each alphabet
  - can you tell me the best approach to solve this problem
  - providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

```js
function sampleFunction() {
  let fruits = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 'f', "g"];
  var fruitsElement = document.getElementById('fruits1');

  fruits.map(item => {
    console.log("item--->", item);
    fruitsElement.innerHTML += item
    return item;
  });

  /*  var fruitsElement = document.getElementById('fruits1');
   for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
     fruitsElement.innerHTML += fruits[i];
   } */

}

function fruitsClick() {
  alert("I am fruit a");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1d2126;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, World</h1>

<button onclick="sampleFunction()">test</button>
<h1 onclick="fruitsClick()" id="fruits1"> </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create separate spans for each fruit name. `fruitsClick()` can then check which span you clicked on and get its text content.

```js
function sampleFunction() {
  let fruits = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 'f', "g"];
  var fruitsElement = document.getElementById('fruits1');

  fruits.forEach(item => {
    console.log("item--->", item);
    fruitsElement.innerHTML += `<span class="fruit">${item}</span>`;
  });
}


function fruitsClick(e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // prevent bubbling from <span> to <h1>
  let fruit = e.target.innerText;
  alert("I am fruit " + fruit);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #1d2126;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, World</h1>

<button onclick="sampleFunction()">test</button>
<h1 onclick="fruitsClick(event)" id="fruits1"> </h1>
```

Comment: hey can you tell me why we are using `.stopPropagation();` this will help me to understand the code much better

Comment: We attached the event listener to the `<h1>`, but we only want to run it when it first fires on the `<span>`. That stops it from continuing to bubble out. Try taking it out and see what happens.